# modify the data of column while copying the data of column from other table

Tags: mysql, sql, mariadb

In mysql, I am trying to copy the data from one column to other column of different table. I have used the below command to achieve this.

```
insert ignore into user(payload) select payload from group;
```

data in old column is **data:test**

data in new column should be **{"payload":"data:test"}**

As of now when I used the above insert command, it just copies the data as is from old column, I want the new column to be updated as **{"payload":"data:test"}**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually that quite simple with the use of the CONCAT() function

```
insert ignore into user(payload) 
    select CONCAT( '{"payload":"', payload, '"}' ) from group;
```

> [A tutorial to explain the CONCAT() function](https://www.mysqltutorial.org/sql-concat-in-mysql.aspx)